# How to refresh a wcf service reference from c# project in Dynamics AX without VS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, axapta

I'm not an expert in Dynamics AX, so I kinda need to ask this question here.

I have the following scenario: i need to consume the wcf service from inside the AX form, so that I'm able to make a call to web service and receive some data. For that purpose I have create a c# project, where I have added my WCF service reference. So far, so good. The next step I need to do is to deploy this assembly that has a ref for my WCF to Dynamics AX. I've seen a couple of tutorials to do that and it looks like AX tools for Visual Studio are good to do that by simply deploying it from within VS.

However when i need to update my service refs on production environment, I may not always have VS with AX tools installed (I can't blame them for that). So that lead me to a question: since VS tools should only be a wrapper on some other AX commands responsible for deploying this .NET assembly to AX, how can i update this assembly manually or by running a script or so.

I have found this article that tells me how to work with managed code in AX and where it is [located](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg889192.aspx).

So my questions are the following:
1. Is it possible to refresh a .NET assembly that has a service reference to my WCF service without having VS+AX tools installed on the server?
2. If so, would it be enough to just copy a new assembly to server-client folders to refresh the assembly?
3. Is there any advanced articles that dive deeper into how AX tools or deploying of a .NET assembly works?

Thanks in advance for reply!

Comment: If you are providing a deliverable to a company that doesn't have local dev tools available, a stand alone assembly would be fine, and yes to `#2` with an AOS restart. You need to answer a few fundamental questions about the purpose of the assembly and your development of it. Is it used by one company or many? Should your users have the ability to customize it or are you an ISV/VAR responsible for its integrity and maintenance? Some of those questions would answer the best way to integrate it.

Comment: Hey Alex! Thanks for your comment! The answers to these questions are: this is going to be used across multiple companies, and yes, we take full responsibility for it's integrity, so we don't want users be able to modify the contents of a project-assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are the provider of the solution you should build and [export](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj720261.aspx) AX Model (includes code, assembly and all dependencies) in your development (build) environment.

At the customer environment you [import / install](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj720288.aspx) the AX Model and compile.

So direct answers to your questions:

1. you should not refresh service in the production environment. Refreshed proxy must be created in the development environment and exported to model, which is imported in (pre-) production environment.
2. depended assemblies are deployed at AOS is restart (as long your proxy is marked as [*Deploy to Server*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg889192.aspx)).
3. - [Deployment of Managed Code Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg889216.aspx)
   - [AX: DLL Auto deploy](http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2013/07/auto-deploying-dlls-and-other-resources.html)
   - Blog: [Assembly Deployment](http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2011/09/ax-2012-net-assembly-deployment.html)
   - White paper: [Deploying Customizations](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26571)

Comment: Thanks Matej for your answer, i think this gonna help me to resolve the issue!